# Salary sacrifice share scheme

Tags: benefits

What questions should I ask a prospective employer that is offering this benefit? This is a new benefit that I have not heard of before.  In researching it, it seemed to be pretty straight forward.  Is there anything I need to know before deciding to accept this benefit?

Comment: How can sacrificing something be a "benefit"? How do you think you will benefit from that?

Comment: Have you asked for details? It's a scheme to lower your pre-tax income.  There really isn't enough information.

Comment: What country?  This sounds similar to an employee stock purchase program in the US but "salary sacrifice" is common nomenclature in Europe.

Comment: Define what "salary sacrifice" is and what this scheme entails and maybe we can help you navigate this. Or more specifically, *ask* this prospective employer what such scheme is, only they know for sure what it actually is (regardless of how it's named)

Comment: I suspect this is UK where salary sacrifica can be used in many ways to buy something but also save on income tax, but with shares in this case (aka instead of getting extra 300 pounds salary you would then spend on shares/car etc, employer pays you 300 less and puts that towards the purchase directly). But we need op to confirm.

Comment: In the USA there is a pre-tax funded Medical Spending Account which can be used to pay for approved medical costs like copays, excess after insurance covered a claim, purchases not covered by insurance etc. Very strict rules for these.

Comment: Hi Becky! With "salary sacrifice", are you referring to this scheme? https://www.gov.uk/guidance/salary-sacrifice-and-the-effects-on-paye

Answer (score 1):

"Salary sacrifice" is a legal way to avoid paying so much tax.  Normally you would take your salary, after tax, and then buy things with it.  Salary sacrifice is where you agree that your employer can give you a pay cut, and in return the employer will buy something for you.  It works because the tax you pay is based on your income - if you take a pay cut, you pay less tax.

In this case, the salary sacrifice is yo buy shares.  Presumably in your employer.

The actual tax saving is likely to be quite small, so you need to look at the whole offer.  Are they offering the shares at a discount on the market rate.  Is there any way to not buy the shares if the price of them starts going down?

As with any buying shares scheme, there's the element of a gamble as you don't know whether the price will go up or down.

Comment: It's worth noting though that there will still be tax obligations on the "benefit", presumably at the time when the granted shares are sold, so it's not so much _avoiding_ the extra tax as it is _deferring_ it.

Comment: In many legislations this would not work. Non-cash benefits are taxable income just as cash unless there is a specific law that exempts them or your are screwing around with the evaluation of these benefits.

Comment: @Hilmar Here in the UK, a salary sacrifice deal may or may not be considered a taxable benefit, depending on what it is.  But National Insurance is always based on income, so there's some benefit there, even if the benefit is taxable.

Comment: For example, an employer can buy a computer for you to use, or pay for childcare in the UK. So this _can_ be quite significant savings.

Comment: @Hilmar In jurisdictions where this model exists, the employer can not freely choose what to buy. Rather there are some specific options, usually related to saving for retirement or something like that that are specifically exempted from the taxes (or have the deferred taxation @ mustaccio mentioned). Essentially the government says, if you put part of your salary towards retirement saving it will not be taxed.